# Setting up a virtual host Wamp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp, virtualhost

I know this question has been asked several times, and ive even done it alot of times in my company, but, now I wanted to set up a virtual host at home and Its not working.

What have I done:

`Added xxx.localhost.de into the hosts`

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 xxx.localhost.de
> ```

`Uncommented include vhosts... in my httpd.conf`

> ```
> Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
> ```

`Set up a virtual host for my project`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin asdr@web.de
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\xxx"
    ServerName xxx.localhost.de
    ServerAlias xxx.localhost.de
    ErrorLog "logs/xxx-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xxx-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I dont get an error - wamp is still starting fine and I can access it by using the normal path 
`localhost/...`
but when i try to reach it over xxx.localhost.de , I get on the website "www.localhost.de". It acts like he does NOT care about my hosts file...

What have I actually missed out? In my company it always worked like this. Ive checked tutorials aswell, and it always says this are all the steps which are needed.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Can you ping `xxx.localhost.de`

Comment: Yes but I think i only get a reply of the website "http://www.localhost.de"

Comment: Yep just checked - it takes the "xxx." as a subdomain and pings www.localhost.de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to make the changes to the `hosts.ics` file, and not the standard `hosts` file. It worked just fine then

Comment: My guess is that if you have a `hosts.ics` (Internet Connection Sharing) it takes preference. But it is not normal to have one.

Comment: It does not appear to be documented by Microsoft, other than one article that has been copied about quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem too, There are couple of things that can cause that, first try to add  DirectoryIndex index.php to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin asdr@web.de
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\xxx"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName xxx.localhost.de
    ServerAlias xxx.localhost.de
    ErrorLog "logs/xxx-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xxx-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

then you can try to write in your browser "http://you_address.local
if this doesn't help,I will think of anything else that can cause that

Comment: I don't think its about the virtualhost. Virtualhost errors causes error in apache-error-log. But i get no error... It acts like the hosts file isnt loaded or smth

Comment: I solved my problem with adding http://  , and can't think of anything else that will cause that, have you tried changing the www. to anything else ??

Comment: Its just not working... I have really no sense. **EVERYTHING** is correct!

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that you are trying yo use something that already exist on the Internet, and it skips your hosts file, but it should not, so maybe you should try to change the name of your local website

Comment: I just went through my questions and realized I've never reported back on this. So here we are 5 years later: It seems I had to make the entries into the `hosts.ics` and not the standard `hosts`. It feels like the hosts file is ignored entirely when a hosts.ics exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

Change the HOSTS file to :-

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       localhost

127.0.0.1 project1.dev
::1       project1.dev
```

And the Vhost definition to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin asdr@web.de
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin asdr@web.de
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\xxx"
    ServerName project1.dev
    ServerAlias www.project1.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/project1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project1-access.log" common
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/xxx">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I just went through my questions and realized I've never reported back on this. So here we are 5 years later: It seems I had to make the entries into the `hosts.ics` and not the standard `hosts`. It feels like the hosts file is ignored entirely when a hosts.ics exists.

Comment: Yes, but it is not usual to have a `hosts.ics` file Are you using Internet Connection Sharing

Comment: tbh I have no idea. I haven't configured it ever atleast. It was just there.

Comment: Then I would suggest removing it, or maybe this question, as your answer which you ticked as correct is only going to confuse others if they find it

Comment: I tried to remove this question but I can't. "Others have put effort into it...". I can remove my answer maybe